# Отсрочка загрузки скриптов и различного контента

Tags: javascript, html

Для уменьшения запросов при загрузки страницы, я некоторый контент подгружаю чуть позже чем страницу.
Например тизерные блоки, которые находятся в конце сайта, зачем их сразу грузить, ведь пользователь может до них даже не докрутить страницу. Для этого я использую такой код:

```
<div id="ad"></div>
<script>
var stat_rig = 0;
jq(window).scroll(function () {
  if (jq(this).scrollTop() > 600 && stat_rig == 0) {
    stat_rig = 1;
    jq('#ad').load("страница_контента");
  }
});
</script>
```

600 - на сколько нужно прокрутить страницу чтобы блок показался
stat_rig - флаг, следит за тем, показан ли этот блок уже, иначе он будет бесконечно его перегружать при скролле ниже 600

**Вопрос:**
Как еще возможно отсрочить загрузку контента, чтобы он загружался строго после всей страницы, не просто последним, а именно после окончания загрузки и построения всей страницы.
Может подскажите какое-то событие, или еще что-то.

Comment: ЕМНИП окончание загрузки и построения DOMа это onload. Ещё в jquery есть $(document).ready. Про события загрузки и отрисовки был доклад на последнем яке (ссылка ниже), но там в контексте отлова момента первой отрисовки хоть чего-то. Но уже точно не помню что именно там было, а по слайдам как-то не вспомнилось деталей, так-что если время есть — глянь.

http://tech.yandex.ru/events/yac/2013/talks/1115/

Answer (score 1):

Пока что решил эту проблему по событию малейшего скрола.
Заменил 600 на 1, и того у меня картинки, и блоки сайта некоторые загружаются только тогда когда осуществляется малейший скролл. Естественно тут я делаю такие участки страницы которые не входят в первый экран, чтобы пользователь не заметил отсутствие этих участков страницы.

Если будут идеи по какому условию еще можно подобное сделать, буду рад совету.

Comment: Кажется это не сработает если листать клавишами

Comment: А почему не подходит событие onload?

Answer (score 0):

А разве эти 2 не подходят?

> чтобы он загружался строго после всей страницы

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  init();
});
```

---

```
window.onload = function() {
  init();
};
```